# Sound problem in ubuntu 16.04 (on wake up and suspend/resume)

Tags: 16.04, sound, suspend

For some reason when I wake my laptop up, there is no sound. No matter what I try through the terminal, or by playing with the volume controls, no audio. I can only get audio working again by a restart.
And when I suspend, and resume, the same issue occurred, no audio.
Does anybody know why, and/or how to fix?

Comment: What is the make and model of your laptop?

Answer (score -1):

Use **Pulse Audio Volume Control** (pavucontrol).  It has more control options over the default **Sound** app.

You can install it with this command:

```
$ sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Run it from the Search button of Ubuntu Launcher by typing `volume`.

From the **Pulse Audio Volume Control** app click on the **Configuration** tab.  Select your preferred profile.  Depending on how many devices you have available, the best one would most likely be one of the **Built-in Audio** profile options.

In my case, **Analog Stereo Output (unplugged)** profile always work.

After making this setting, going back to the **default Sound** app and clicking on the closest match (which again has the words **Built-in Audio** included in the description, will bring the sound back.

The only time this has failed to bring back the sound for me was on a few occasions where my external sound system was either physically disconnected or turned down.

I know the latter isn't your case, because rebooting has brought your sound back.